# Rspec / capybara fails when plain text email templates are added to features in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rspec, capybara

I am testing a html email (`somemail.html.erb`) email in rails with the following code:

```
last_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(last_email.body.raw_source)
fragment.at_css('[id="some-id"]').attr('href')
```

This looks for an link with an id in the code, and then get the url to follow it later in a test.

However if I add a `somemail.text.erb` file the test suit breaks.

How do I get the config on my test suit to look at the html email, or even better look at both emails? I have to currently move my text emails out the map to get the feature tests to run and pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email objects stored in `deliveries` should have the html and text parts available separately via `html_part` and `text_part`. So to look at the html only part you'd do something like

```
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(last_email.html_part.body.to_s)
```

Note: Since you're using capybara there is a gem that can make this sort of testing/email link following easier called `capybara-email`

Comment: That's brilliant thanks. And that gem suggestion is great too, I'll move over to that at some point.